# How to specify a rectangle on a datetimeaxis plot?

Tags: python, holoviews

I want to draw a Rectangle (hv.Bounds) on a plot that has a datetime axis. However it's not clear from the documentation how one would specify the corner points.

Naturally I tried to specify a datetime object, however this results in the following error message:
`ValueError: lbrt: tuple element is not numeric`

```py
import holoviews as hv
import pandas as pd
hv.extension('bokeh')


%%opts Curve [width=500]
xs = pd.date_range('1.1.2019', '31.1.2019')
ys = np.sin(range(len(xs)))
box=hv.Bounds((pd.to_datetime('5.1.2019'), 0.1, pd.to_datetime('7.1.2019'), .8))
hv.Curve((xs,ys))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of version `1.12.3` it's possible to do this:

```
import holoviews as hv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import hvplot.pandas
hv.extension('bokeh')

index = pd.date_range('1.1.2019', '2.28.2019')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(len(index)), index)
pts = pd.to_datetime(['1.15.2019', '2.15.2019'])
box = hv.Bounds((pts[0], 0.1, pts[1], .9)).opts(color='red')
df.hvplot.scatter() * box
```

Answer (score 0):

As of now, `Bounds` only accepts numeric bounds, but see this PR if you feel like testing it: https://github.com/pyviz/holoviews/pull/3640